# Copy data from one table to another - Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to connect to an Oracle DB from C#.

I need to:

1. connect to schema A, read all rows from table T and insert all of them to table T in schema X
2. connect to schema B, read all rows from table T and insert all of them to table T in schema X
3. connect to schema C, read all rows from table T and insert all of them to table T in schema X

Basically I need to copy all data from tables in 3 different schemas (each one using different credentials) into one table in fourth schema. I don't need to modify the data between reading from schema A/B/C and inserting it into X - just a straight copy. All 4 tables have identical structure (DDL).

I was thinking of using 3 datasets as sort of an intermediate step but maybe it could be done easier?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ManagedDataAccess, but if users A, B, C (respective owners of schemas `A`, `B`, `C`) have `insert` privileges on table `X`.`T`, then all it takes is a single query: `insert into X.T select * from A.T`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think owners of schemas A, B, C can (directly) write to X.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done entirely within the database and does not need to go through an external application.

From a user(s) with appropriate permissions to grant permissions on `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
GRANT SELECT ON A.T TO X;
GRANT SELECT ON B.T TO X;
GRANT SELECT ON C.T TO X;
```

From user `X`:

```
INSERT INTO X.T
SELECT * FROM A.T;

INSERT INTO X.T
SELECT * FROM B.T;

INSERT INTO X.T
SELECT * FROM C.T;
```

Or as a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO X.T
SELECT * FROM A.T UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B.T UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM C.T;
```

From that first user(s) with appropriate permissions:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON A.T FROM X;
REVOKE SELECT ON B.T FROM X;
REVOKE SELECT ON C.T FROM X;
```

Comment: Looks interesting, I will try that. And of course I need to do is in C# since this is only a first step in a complicated process.

Comment: Well, it won't work. It seems that these tables are completely isolated by firewall etc. so I basically **have** to use the intermediate step in order to 'join' data from all 3 of them into 1 table. So my question still stands - can it be done easier than using DataSet in the middle.

Comment: @rincEwind Yes you can take the data out of the database and put it back in somewhere else but if you are then bypassing those "firewalls" (if they are actual firewalls between different servers or something you are calling a "firewall" but is just two different schemas without the appropriate grants between them) then you need to talk to your DBA and data architect about the appropriateness of the "firewall" rules and whether there is a better (in-database) way to manage this .... because skipping those firewall rules does not seem like a good starting point.